# How to add leading zeros in ADF data flow from the expression builder

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

How to add leading zeros in ADF data flow from the expression builder

For example – have column with numeric value as “000001” but it is coming as 1 only in SQL DB , if I put in  entire value in single quotes it is coming but I need dynamic way of implementation with out hard coding.

Comment: Numerical data types don't have leading 0's. If you want to have leading zeroes, you must use a string based data type.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@Larnu**'s comments that even if we give `00001` to an int type column it will give as `1` only.

So, we have to give those in single quotes (`'00001'`) to use like that or import the incoming data as string instead of int.

As you are using ADF dataflow, if you want to use the `00001`, you can generate those using **derived column transformation** from SQL source. But this depends on your requirement like how your leading 0's varies. So, use according to it.

**Sample demo:**

```
concat('0000', toString(id))
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Use that column as per your requirement, after that you can convert it back to the same input by `toInteger(id)`.